# React Router doesn't render component with <Link to="/" />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a pretty simple example and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't make my  navigate the user back to my homepage. It will render the homepage fine (which is a PostCollection) when I refresh the page on /, but my Link which navigates back to / from other components does not work. It is simply updating the url in the url bar, but not loading the other component.

Example Code, truncated for brevity:

```
const App:React.SFC = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router basename={ROUTE_ROOT}>
                <>
                    <Header/>
                    <MainContainer>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/' exact component={PostCollection}/>
                            <Route path='/page/:page' exact component={PostCollection}/>
                            <Route path='/:year/:month/:day/:post' exact component={Post}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </MainContainer>
                    <Footer/>
                </>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Then in my Header component as shown in my main App:

```
const Header:React.SFC = () => {
    return (
        <header className="flex">
            <Link to='/'>
                Go Home
            </Link>
        </header>
    );
};

export default memo( Header );
```

The simple  here only updates the url to my root, but does not rerender with my PostCollection component. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This usually happens when you're using other Higher Order Components in conjunction with React Router. Is that the case?

Comment: I have a redux provider wrapped around it, but that's it. Could this be causing issues?

Comment: Yeah, try changing the order of wrapping, that might fix it.